# What should you do when your professor disagrees with your research direction?

Tags: research-process, advisor, masters, conflict-of-interest

I am a graduate student working to get my master's degree, but my professor and I have differences in research directions. While his personality is very strong, I don't think he is capable enough in his chosen research direction.

On the other hand, I have already produced certain results in the research direction I am interested in. I have also completed a manuscript submission and am currently waiting for opinions. I was tortured every day by hesitating between the tasks he assigned me and my interests. what should I do?

Comment: Declaring a professor to be incapable in his own research is a bold claim.

Comment: Did you have a discussion about this with your professor? What did he say?

Comment: You haven't described that he "disagrees with your research direction," only that he has assigned you tasks *you* disagree with.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as a Master's student, your time in the program and with your advisor is limited. Therefore, if you're interested in conducting research and publishing it, it's clear to me that clashing with your advisor should be avoided. I also hope that you have never expressed these thoughts about your advisor's capabilities, either to him or to fellow students.

That being said, it's positive that you have results in the research direction you prefer. But you should find common ground with your advisor's interests and follow his research agenda, if for no other reason than political but also for your own benefit. After completing the requirements set by your advisor, you can then discuss publishing the results you have.